Generator Function Not iterating
I am trying to get some values populated in a pie plot. The code worked initially, however now it just shows one of the values on the plot. Two errors that I get.

It sometimes shows gne_pct to be a function and reminds me that I cannot use next

When I call the generator it gives me only one value, where as pct is a list.


pct=[]
Total=pvt_meth_sect.value.sum()
for val in pvt_meth_sect.value:
   pct.append((val/Total)*100)

gne_pct = lambda x : (x for x in pct)
type(gne_pct(pct))

plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))

sect_grph=plt.pie(pvt_meth_sect.value,labels=pvt_meth_sect.index,
    colors='rgby',autopct=str(next(gne_pct(pct))))
plt.show()

Output>>>>>>>>>
[43.127589443560346,36.982427463914306,0.10365485692718165, 19.786328235598162]


I was trying to create a pie plot and populate the percentage value of the categories that make up the pie plot.

What is pvt_meth_sect? Please provide a [mre].

You are giving the string of the first value to autopct instead of a function (str() and next() are called in your code, not passed as functions). You should check out matplotlib's example if you haven't already: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-and-donut-labels-py

pvt_meth_sect = pd.pivot_table(data=df_meth,index=df_meth['EPA-Report-sector'],values=df_meth[['value']],aggfunc='sum')
It's a pivot. And the libraries imported are the following:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

Is there a solution someone can suggest? Does the code work for you?
